# $\int_0^2 u\phi' dx=-\int_0^1 \phi dx - \phi(1)$

Tags: calculus, partial-differential-equations, partial-derivative

Evans page 244 gives example $2$.

They have that $\phi\in C_c^\infty(U)$ is a test function and have let:
$$u(x)=\begin{cases}x& \text{if }0\leq x<1\\
2&\text{if }1<x<2\end{cases}$$

Then they have the following calculation:

$$\int_0^2 u(x)\phi'(x) dx=\int_0^1 x\phi'(x) dx+2\int_1^2 \phi'(x) dx$$
which is fine, and then they write:
$$=-\int_0^1 \phi(x) dx - \phi(1).$$
Where the first term is just an application of integration by parts. How is the second one obtained?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By integrating by parts
$$\int_0^1 x\phi'(x) dx+2\int_1^2 \phi'(x) dx=\left[x\phi(x)\right]_0^1-\int_0^1 \phi(x) dx+2\left[\phi(x)\right]_1^2\\
=\phi(1)-0-\int_0^1 \phi(x) dx+2\phi(2)-2\phi(1)=-\int_0^1 \phi(x) dx - \phi(1)$$
where $\phi(2)=0$ because $\phi$ has compact support in $U=(0,2)$ (see Example 2 at p. 244 in "Partial differential equations" by Evans).

Comment: Dumb question, but why does $\int_{\partial (0,1)} x\phi(x)\nu^1 dS = [x\phi(x)]_0^1$? We get a normal vector at $0$ and $1$, pointing outwards right?

Comment: @calculus. Yes that's right. Anyway we are in one-dimension here.

Comment: Sorry, I am just not sure how these are equal. Just to roughly say what I am thinking, it feels like I get $\nu(1)=1$ and $\nu(0)=-1$? Both are unit vectors facing in different directions? Then this gives us  $$\int_{\partial (0,1)} x\phi(x)\nu^1 dS=(1)\phi(1)\nu(1)+(0)\phi(0)\nu(0)=\phi(1)$$

Which is right in this case I guess

Comment: Okay nvm, I guess that makes sense, reconciling the Evans multidimensional integration by parts, with the one variable one.

Thank you!